# transpose multiple columns into one column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to transpose 3 columns to be in a new column. My data is similar to:

```
id   stage   A   B   C
1     p      0   2   1
2     q      0   1   3
```

and I expected to be like:

```
id   stage  type  value
1     p      A     0
1     p      B     2
1     p      C     1
2     q      A     0
2     q      B     1
2     q      C     3
```

I tried this following code before but it did not give me the desired result

```
df.melt(id_vars = ['id', 'stage'], var_name = 'type', value_name = 'value')
```

How can I get my desired result with python? Thank you.

Comment: You  missed 'sort_values'. You can get the result you have shown with `df.melt(id_vars = ['id', 'stage'], var_name = 'type', value_name = 'value').sort_values('id')`

Comment: thank you! but it resulted that one of the columns did not appear at the new columns

Comment: I do not understand, it shows me exactly as you have in the 'expected output'.